# Z3 on non-x86 architectures

Tags: z3, bus-error

I was checking the portability of a tool using Z3 (2012-12-21 git version, the latest "master" release), and thus tried compiling Z3 on Sparc64. I had to fiddle with `src/util/hwf.cpp` so that it would treat Sparc64, and not just IA64, as lacking SIMD intrinsics and `emmintrin.h`. The compilation succeeded.

Unfortunately, the resulting executable crashes on startup with a bus error in `prime_generator::prime_generator()`. I have no idea why.

```
Program received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
0x009b1dac in global constructors keyed to _ZN15prime_generatorC2Ev ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x009b1dac in global constructors keyed to _ZN15prime_generatorC2Ev ()
```

This is not very important for me (our machines are x86 or x86-64) but may be relevant for some embedded applications.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a question for StackOverflow. Did you mean to post this on the Issues page for that project, instead?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's not a question, it's a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there has been any interest in running Z3 on non-x86 machines, so it's highly likely that you'll find a few problems.

SPARC, in particular, doesn't allow unalighed memory accesses, as x86 does.
From a quick look, I could see several points where the unaligned could come from.
For example, memory::allocate() dealigns the pointer returned by malloc by sizeof(size_t). If that's not 64 bits, then it will crash (because of the svector data).
Then, svector allocation, also reserves 2*sizeof(unsigned) before the data. If 2*sizeof(unsigned) is not a multiple of sizeof(uint64), then you'll get a crash.

And so on.  The point is that without more info, it's impossible to help you. You need to compile with -g, and if needed print the assembly code where it's crashing to help pin point the exact location.

Also, don't use the master branch, please.  That's very old. Please consider using the unstable branch  (it's not that bad as the name may sound :)